# Visualizing A System of Nonlinear Differential Equations

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I've been investigating the existence of solutions to the system
$$\begin{equation*}
\left \{
\begin{split}
x'(t)&=p(t)f(y(t))\\
y'(t)&=q(t)g(x(t)).
\end{split}
\right .
\end{equation*}$$

where $p(t),\; q(t): [a,\infty) \to (0, \infty)$  are continuous,
$f(r): \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$  is continuous
with $rf(r)> 0$ for $r \neq 0$;
$g(r): \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous
with $rg(r)> 0$ for $r \neq 0$;
$f(r)$ and $g(r)$ are invertible.

I would like to visualize graphically a solution to the system, but this system doesn't easily lend itself to creating an example. Any thoughts on functions that might satisfy this system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than starting with the equations and trying to find a solution, start with the solution.

Try starting with $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ some convenient smooth functions that are positive and increasing, and any $f$ and $g$ satisfying your conditions on them, and take
$p(t) = x'(t)/f(y(t))$ and $q(t) = y'(t)/g(x(t))$.